Why is my Google Apps Script function slowing down increasingly the longer the runtime gets?
I've already optimized this code block as much as possible so that it is only making one singular call to getRange/setValues at the very end. This block is looping through thousands of rows of data in a separate dataset spreadsheet, and identifying the "top" items for a number of different categories.
the top category #1 and top category #2 code block execute according to my logs in approximately 1 minute, maybe a bit longer. The top category #3 code block is suddenly taking 6 minutes to execute, and the top category #4 code block is then taking 8 minutes to execute, and it just continuously gets longer as the script duration goes on.
These blocks are quite literally identical to one another, other than swapping out essentially which column of data they are referring to in the original dataset, and once again only make a call to write to the spreadsheet once at the very end. Is anyone else experiencing something like this, or understand what could cause it? Also note that i have very, very few equations in the spreadsheet that recalculate as more data is added. And the most complex one is a simple sum. Please help, and see example code below.
(Note: this code has been edited down greatly to hide identifying info about what the data at hand is, and also to exclude attributes as there are more than just 3. but i tried to capture all of the scenarios, where some are sums of attributes, and some are the count of attributes; if you see any typos / inconsistent variable names, know that is just from my editing down, and it isn't actually impacting the code as it works when I run it, just increasingly slowly with each category block as i mentioned)
Thank you in advance!
let topCategorySheet = active_spread.getSheetByName('Top Category');
let allInCategoryArray = [];
let allInCategoryArrayAttribute1 = [];
let allInCategoryArrayAttribute2 = [];
let allInCategoryArrayAttribute3 = [];
let allInCategoryArrayAttribute1Sum=0;
let allInCategoryArrayAttribute2Sum=0;

for (var each=0;each<allValuesInDataSet.length;each++) {

  if (new Date(dateValuesInDataSet[each])>=new Date(currStartDate)&&new Date(dateValuesInDataSet[each])<=new Date(currEndDate)) {
    allInCategoryArray.push(allCategoryValuesInDataSet[each]); }; };
 
let uniqueCategoryArray = [...new Set(allInCategoryArray.flat(1))];
let finalUniqueCategoryArray = []
let finalUniqueCategoryArrayAttribute1 = [];
let finalUniqueCategoryArrayAttribute2 = [];
let finalUniqueCategoryArrayAttribute3 = [];

for (var each1=0;each1<uniqueCategoryArray.length;each1++) {
  finalUniqueCategoryArray.push(uniqueCategoryArray[each1])

  allInCategoryArrayAttribute1=[];
  allInCategoryArrayAttribute2=[];
  allInCategoryArrayAttribute3=[];

  for (var each2=0;each2<dateValues.length;each2++) {
    //all if statement
    if (new Date(dateValuesInDataSet[each2])>=new Date(currStartDate)&&new Date(dateValuesInDataSet[each2])<=new Date(currEndDate)&&drugClassValues[each2]==allInCategoryArray [each1]) {
      allInCategoryArrayAttribute1.push(Attribute1ValuesInDataSet[each2]); 
      allInCategoryArrayAttribute2.push(Attribute2ValuesInDataSet[each2]);
      allInCategoryArrayAttribute3.push(Attribute3ValuesInDataSet[each2]);
      };      
     };

  allInCategoryArrayAttribute1Sum=0;
    for(var each3=0;each3<allInCategoryArrayAttribute1.length;each3++){
      if (!isNaN(allInCategoryArrayAttribute1[each3])){
        allInCategoryArrayAttribute1Sum+= parseFloat(allInCategoryArrayAttribute1[each3]); }; };  
  finalUniqueCategoryArrayAttribute1.push(allInCategoryArrayAttribute1Sum);

  allInCategoryArrayAttribute2Sum=0;
    for(var each4=0;each4<allInCategoryArrayAttribute2.length;each4++){
      if (!isNaN(allInCategoryArrayAttribute2[each4])){
        allInCategoryArrayAttribute2Sum+= parseFloat(allInCategoryArrayAttribute2[each4]); }; };  
  finalUniqueCategoryArrayAttribute2.push(allInCategoryArrayAttribute2Sum); };

  finalUniqueCategoryArrayAttribute3.push(allInCategoryArrayAttribute2.length);

};


let numRowsForFinalArray = 25;
let valuesArrayFinal = [];
for (var eachy5=0;each5<uniqueCategoryArray.length;each5++) {
  valuesArrayFinal.push([finalUniqueCategoryArrayAttribute1[each5],finalUniqueCategoryArrayAttribute2[each5],finalUniqueCategoryArrayAttribute3[each5]])
};

function compareNumbers(a,b) {
  if(a[2] > b[2])
    return -1; 
  if(a[2] < b[2])
    return 1;  
};

  valuesArrayFinal = valuesArrayFinal.sort(compareNumbers);
  valuesArrayFinal = valuesArrayFinal.slice(0,numRowsForFinalArray);
  topCategorySheet.getRange(7,3,numRowsForFinalArray,3).setValues(valuesArrayFinal);

Have optimized as much as possible and am still experiencing slowdowns.

Try debugging as  written in [mre]. First step is to start from scratch(Don't start with what you have and cut down)-add/create mock data  using random data in script, without touching spreadsheet and try to reproduce the issue live.

Just to back TheMaster's comment, right now it's quite hard to follow what's going on in your code.

This block is looping through thousands of rows of data in a separate dataset spreadsheet - How many rows and columns exactly? The more data you process the more performance is going to suffer.

May not be relevant, but block3  and 4 uses parseFloat, while 1 and 2 doesn't.

The code you show seems fine. Chances are that the bad performance you mention is caused by the spreadsheet rather than the script. To improve spreadsheet performance, see my optimization tips.
